# Saved Image on Heroku Not Visible on Served Webpage

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I receive an image via Flask and save response.content to a PNG file on Heroku. The name of this image is then passed to the calling function, which uses the filename in served HTML. I verify the file exists right after saving it, have tested the file integrity offline and everything works; but a second after saving it on Heroku it doesn't exist when served up in the web page. The server logs are as follows:

```
2020-10-08T20:07:00.542480+00:00 app[web.1]: saved fast_graph to disk @ temp/a45329e9-b76b-4714-9e5a-3463b1b6eaf1.png
2020-10-08T20:07:00.542502+00:00 app[web.1]: verified file: temp/a45329e9-b76b-4714-9e5a-3463b1b6eaf1.png
2020-10-08T20:07:01.934587+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.251.139 - - [08/Oct/2020:20:07:01 +0000] "GET /temp/a45329e9-b76b-4714-9e5a-3463b1b6eaf1.png HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "http://XXX.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0"
2020-10-08T20:07:01.937442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/temp/a45329e9-b76b-4714-9e5a-3463b1b6eaf1.png" host=XXX.herokuapp.com request_id=37f77e3b-35ce-4355-b5ca-84b84a51718b fwd="X.X.191.107" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
```

Is this a property of Heroku's ephemeral filesystem or am I doing something wrong? My code is as follows:

```
# get file path of generated chart
response = requests.get(
    if90_clientbase + f"?client_id={client_id}&action={api_action}")

# check the outcome
outcome = response.json().get("outcome")
if not outcome:
    return False

# get the filename and fetch the file
file_name = response.json().get("value")
response = requests.get (if90_filesbase + f"?file_name={file_name}")

# generate filename, save fetched content
save_file = f"{temp_folder}{lib_misc.unique_filename()}.png"
with open(save_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)

return save_file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. Files and folders in the development tree don't map to the web folder view. If you face a similar issue, a good place to begin is your /static folder.